# Identify selected option using v-model in select box

Tags: arrays, data-binding, vue.js

I have a filter list using a select tag. I want to be able to filter the array based on the option selected. I have tried using v-model as this works with checkboxes but unfortunately doesn't work with select fields.

Any help would be amazing.

Please find my fiddle attached

```
<div id="app">
  Selected: {{concatenated}}
  <select>
    <option v-for="item in vals" :select="item.selected">{{item.value}}</option>
  </select>
  <!--
  <div v-for="item in vals">
    <p>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="item.selected">{{item.value}}
    </p>  
  </div>
  -->
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/39jb3fzw/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the docs and how they do databinding with `select`.

https://jsfiddle.net/s3x096u3/1/

```
<select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="item in vals" :value="item.value" :key="item.value">{{item.value}}</option>
  </select>
```

With regards to your code, a `select` attribute on an `option` element doesn't do anything.

Comment: Yeah, I have checked out the docs and worked it out but I want the computed value to control the output rather than the selected value declared in data. Is there a way around this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I want the computed value to control the output", and why do you want that?

Comment: I am going to be working with one array and 3 select boxes. Each select box when selected will update the array and the output is based on what is in the array. Hope that made sense.

Comment: Sure. Just declare 3 values in your `data`, and make a computed property that returns an array with these 3 values.

Comment: You just linked the same thing in your question.

Comment: Try now. My apologies

Comment: Yeah, like that